# User has mysql permission for select only but phpMyAdmin allows edit

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Why would a user with permission to only select be able to edit a record in phpMyAdmin? How can I prevent the edit?

This is the permissions screen:
[image: permissions]

Comment: How do these people login to phpMyAdmin? Is login automatic or do they have to enter a userid password

Comment: userid and password

Comment: So they have to login from the phpMyAdmin login page right?

Comment: If that is the case then the userid's are probably setup incorrectly

Comment: Yes, they have to login from the phpMyAdmin login page. I added a screenshot of the permission settings to the question.

Comment: I cannot tell much from that, no idea which user this is a picture of and whether your user is loging in using that account

Comment: Those are issues that I triple checked before posting the question. It's the same user.

Answer (score 1):

If the user is able to edit and save the row in phpMyAdmin, it's because the rights at the MySQL level permit this action. Ultimately it's MySQL that controls what is possible, not phpMyAdmin. Note that it's a combination of username + hostname that applies, so maybe there is the same username with a different hostname that is defined. Also, there can be rights at the global, database, table and column levels.